# In Google Drive SDK, how to upload a new file content

Tags: google-drive-api

I know there is a method files/insert (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), but the documentation doesn't specify where to put the actual file content. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quickstart examples, showing upload, choose your own language:**

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

**Examples for inserting, showing upload choose your language:**

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

**Description of the upload protocol:**

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

Comment: Ah thanks Ali, missed the "Description of the upload protocol" page. Maybe it could be great to just mention this page in the files/insert documentation? Thanks anyway!