# How can I upload a file in my local to my google drive by using Python Google drive APIs?

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

I have a file in my computer and I want to upload it by using Python google drive api,

How can I do it?

Comment: Its Simple, read the documents [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads?hl=en)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Google Drive SDK, how to upload a new file content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162961/in-google-drive-sdk-how-to-upload-a-new-file-content)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Python quickstart in the Google Drive SDK documentation, it shows how to write a simple app to upload a file to Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python